# Need help to Write a subquery in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, rdbms

I have `CUSTOMER` TABLE which contains below column:

```
Customer_name, customer_id, creation_date, last_update_date
```

We need to insert the value from Customers table to another table `Customer_1` which contains below column:

```
Customer_name, customer_id, Hire_date
```

The requirement is like below:

- I need to write a single query,
- When count =1 group by customer_id from Customer table, then insert into Customer_1 table Customer_name, customer_id and Hire_date as Creation date else Customer_name, customer_id and Hire_date=Last_update_Date

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Do. you want one row per `customer_id` or the same number of rows as in the original table?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
insert into customer_1 (customer_id, customer_name, hire_date)
with temp as
  (select a.customer_id, 
          count(*) cnt
   from customer a
   group by a.customer_id
  )
select c.customer_id,
       c.customer_name,
       case when t.cnt = 1 then c.creation_date
            else c.last_update_date
       end as hire_date
from customer c join temp t on t.customer_id = c.customer_id;
```

Comment: Thanks... So, can we write like below:

insert into customer_1 (customer_id, customer_name, hire_date)
select c.customer_id,
       c.customer_name,
       case when t.cnt = 1 then c.creation_date
            else c.last_update_date
       end as hire_date
from customer c join (select a.customer_id, 
          count(*) cnt
   from customer a
   group by a.customer_id
  ) t on t.customer_id = c.customer_id;

Comment: You're welcome. That's the same query, but yours uses an inline view while I opted for a CTE. Otherwise, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function like this:

```
insert into customer_1 (Customer_name, customer_id, Hire_date)
    select customer_name, customer_id, 
           (case when count(*) over (partition by customer_id) = 1
                 then creation_date else last_update_date
            end) as hire_date
    from customer;
```